# Can I use "Admin Select Box to Select2" plugin on frontend?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jquery-select2

I'm using a plugin that has a 2-step dropdown for selecting a taxonomy.  The frontend user selects a location from a dropdown selector.  If the location has a child location, a second dropdown selector appears with the child location(s).  The list is really long and I would like to be able to filter the list with a text field.  Can I alter "Admin Select Box to Select2" plugin so that it will function on the frontend?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-select-box-to-select2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, by editing Plugin's core files, which is not recommended, but if you do not update the plugin it will be fine (or write your own method by copying plugin, it's rather a simple one).

Last line in file admin-select-box-to-select2.php, change:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'amm_select2_enqueue');
```

to

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'amm_select2_enqueue');
```